# Access a collection from a different router/view

Tags: backbone.js

I'm still kind of new to Backbone, and I'm pretty stumped by this...

I have a router/collection/view for Titles, and a router/collection/view for Campaigns.

When a user creates a new campaign, it must be associated with a title. So in the create form, I need to access the list of all titles so I can get their names and (rails) IDs.

I'm not sure how to access this title list from within my Campaigns view though.

A few thoughts on solutions:

1. Using an association library like ligature -- this seems like a lot of work for a fairly straightforward problem, and I don't really need associations.. I just need the full list of titles.
2. Declaring my Titles collection in the global scope and passing it to the initializer of the Titles router.
3. Create a Titles collection in the Campaigns router.. this seems pretty redundant.

Happy to post code, but I don't know what is relavent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by global scope you mean `window`, I'd recommend avoiding that if possible. Do your Titles / Campaign classes have access to a shared scope?  E.g.:

```
( function () {

  var App = {};

  // ...

  // Titles code

  var titles = App.titles = new Backbone.Collection;

  // ...

  // Campaign code

  var titles = App.titles;

} )();
```

You might want to arrange things so the various parts of your app have access to a shared scope like that if you want to have a single Titles collection used throughout the app.

Otherwise if that's impractical or undesirable for some reason, you could just create a separate Titles collection in your Campaigns section and fetch it from the server, or bootstrap it, or however you want to populate it.

It's hard to be more specific without seeing some code, so maybe this will suggest some code that you think would be relevant to post.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just using the code you provided. I assume I can call titles.fetch() from the Campaign code without problem?

Comment: Yeah, it's just an instance, so you can call any of the instance methods like `fetch()`, and as long as you're accessing the same instance from the various parts of your code you should get the desired result.